# SQL - Get the names instead of ID

Tags: mysql

I have a table called `tbl_appointment` which has 2 foreign keys: `idclient` and `idemployee` which they are referencing `tbl_persons`.
So what i want to do is instead of getting the `id` of `idclient` and `idemployee`, i want to get the names `(name,last_name,last_sname)` which they belong to those `id`.

**Query**

```
SELECT CONCAT(tbl_persons.name,' ',tbl_persons.last_name,' ',tbl_persons.last_sname) as fullname, tbl_appointment.*
FROM tbl_appointment
INNER JOIN tbl_persons ON tbl_persons.idpersons = tbl_appointment.idemployee 
INNER JOIN tbl_persons ON tbl_persons.idpersons = tbl_appointment.idclient
WHERE idclient= '$user';
```

Comment: Can You Show your query?

Comment: Can you add the structure of your tables?

Comment: @elegant-user Done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following query, using a [`LEFT JOIN`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/left-join-optimization.html) instead of `INNER JOIN`:

```
SELECT 
    CONCAT(p1.name, ' ', p1.last_name, ' ', p1.last_sname) AS client_fullname,
    CONCAT(p2.name, ' ', p2.last_name, ' ', p2.last_sname) AS employee_fullname
FROM tbl_appointment ta 
    LEFT JOIN tbl_persons p1 ON ta.idclient = p1.idpersons
    LEFT JOIN tbl_persons p2 ON ta.idemployee = p2.idpersons
WHERE ta.idclient = '$user'
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the following

```
SELECT
  app.*,
  CONCAT(client.name,' ',client.last_name,' ',client.last_sname) AS client_full_name,
  CONCAT(empl.name,' ',empl.last_name,' ',empl.last_sname) AS empl_full_name
FROM tbl_appointment app
LEFT JOIN tbl_persons client ON app.idclient=client.id
LEFT JOIN tbl_persons empl ON app.idemployee=empl.id
WHERE app.idclient= '$user'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code: Only thing is you have to select the clients and employees separately, together is more difficult

```
SELECT name,last_name,last_sname 
    FROM tbl_persons WHERE id IN (
      SELECT DISTINCT idclient FROM tbl_appointment;
    ); -- This will select all the clients

SELECT name,last_name,last_sname 
FROM tbl_persons WHERE id IN (
  SELECT DISTINCT idemployee FROM tbl_appointment;
); -- This will select all the employees
```